# How to load the data of a variable that contains CSV file data into table using MySQL and PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using session variable for csv data storage. But I do not know the value of `$file_location` since I am using session variable. So I am not unable to execute my query. Is there a way to load data using
`$file_data` variable.

```php
$file_data = $_SESSION['file_data'];
$file_location = str_replace("\\", "/", $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

$query_1 = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file_data.'" IGNORE INTO TABLE customer_table
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (@column1,@column2,@column3,@column4)
  SET customer_first_name = @column1, customer_last_name = @column2,  customer_email
  = @column3, customer_gender = @column4';

$statement = $connect->prepare($query_1);
```

Comment: You could write the variable to a temporary file and then load that file.

Comment: I recommend you to create stored procedure which receives `$file_data` name as a parameter, checks it for validity and vulnerability absence then loads the data into the table using prepared statement and reports the result. PS. What is the reason in intermediate variables usage? load the data into destination columns directly. PPS. `$file_location` variable is used nowhere.